# asp.net mvc combobox with filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have a little problem in my form for entering some data for my users and that is a lot's of dropdowns, and i saw an a example of a dropdownlist where i can actualy type in it like in textbox and i get the options which contains my entered string.
To be more cleared, example is this: http://www.obout.com/mvc-combobox/autocomplete/aspnet_filtering.aspx
I have been using jquery autocomplete but that is not what i want in this case.
Any ideas or advices are welcome!

[EDIT]
Answer would be: http://tpeczek.com/2010/05/jquery-autocomplete-in-aspnet-mvc.html
With little modifications ofcourse!

Comment: I'm a little confused, you want the comboxbox that you've linked - why can't you use it?  What is wrong with autocomplete with jQuery? What is the problem/exception/etc?

Comment: That example i linked is a component which i have to pay to use it :) autocomplete is autocomplete and it doesn't do searching, my idea is dropdown and textbox above dropdown, and the part where typing in the textbox show options from dropdown..

Comment: solution would be: http://tpeczek.blogspot.com/2010/05/jquery-autocomplete-in-aspnet-mvc.html
with little modifications
it's better to use your own solution with some modifications than payin 1000$ for some controls, where you need just one component!